# Which come first, PCA, FFT, filtering

Tags: fft, filters, algorithms

Might be a simple question, but I keep second guessing my algorithm, so a confirmation would be good. I first do bandpass filtering, then PCA, then FFT of the top principle components.

I also do some sine wave fitting on the filtered data, and on the principle components, but it doesnt make sense to do it on the fft data? Right?

Thank you for your patience on this stupid question.

Comment: What is your application? Where does your data come from? Is it multi-channel? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Radar, multichannel, detection of small scale movement that follows predictable patterns, lots of noise. I want to find the movement and find the "strength" of movement, e.g. size, confirm speed and cycles (as observed by independent measures). So I need a sine wave fitting to find amplitudes, as I guess thats were the "strength" would be hidden given that frequency and distances are constant.

Comment: Could you describe you problem with some background and math? What are you trying to do, what is the mode of the signals, etc..

Comment: You can FFT your PCA data. You can PCA your FFT data. You can do any order of operations on anything, depending on the underlying application, and what you are trying to decipher. You need to add more exact details to your problem.

Comment: Im trying to pick out a sinusoidal signal in a certain freq. range in noise. The signal is present in 1 or more samples of a 512 sample matrix. Alas, a multivariate frequency analasysis. But since i need to find the amplitude and frequency that describes what im measuring best (say pulse) it seems that I cant only do a spectral analysis (e.g. periodogram). I thus use an iterative sinewave fitting that searches for the one and only sine wave that describes my signal the best. Does this explain better? What specific part of my description is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally PCA, FFT could be interchanged without changing anything.

e.g.

```
[U,~,~] = svd(A);
[FU,~,~] = svd(fft(A));
```

fft(U) and FU are the same (up to an arbitrary phase rotation)

However, it may help speed to do BPF first, then FFT, and discard the stopband to reduce dimensionality before doing PCA.

Comment: Thanks. Follow up question: FFT transforms the signal from time to freq space. So you can in effect see the frequencies the signal is made up of (yes?). However, if I am only interested in one frequency, say 10 hz, fitting a sinewave of 10 hz to the signal, would give me some numbers of how pronounced the 10 hz signal is?  Or do you really have to go through the FFT and spectral analysis methods to find the signal you know is there?

Comment: If all you want is one frequency, then a direct inner product with the sinusoidal vector (one coefficient of DFT) is faster than an FFT.   You might also look into "Goetzel filter"

Comment: Im a little unsure what you mean by direct inner product ... The thing is that I want to test two signals with the same frequency (estimated at 439-442 hz), but where one has less energy than the other. Lower amplitude. Doing a DFT (or goertzel) around this range would give a spike as expected at e.g 440 hz, but will the magnitude of the spike be a good measure of energy/amplitude of the signal? What excactly does the spike tell me? On the other hand, doing a fit of all sinus waves in the range (439-442 hz) and pick the best, then estimating amplitude, seems logical to me, but is it?